# RPy2 - 2.1.7 Installation problems on WIN XP

Tags: windows, r, installation, rpy2

Good morning everybody,
I'm really struggling during the installation of rpy version 2.1.7 on a windows XP machine.
I put the correct path in the environmental variable (C:\R\R-2.10.0\bin called R_HOME). 
The installation process appear to accept the entry and it does not give the message "no R Command in the PATH" and it starts the installation.

However, after a little while it gives me the folowing error:

> File "C:\python26\lib\site-packages\setuptools\package-index.py", line 475, in 
>   fetch_distribution
>   return dist.clone(location=self.download(dist.location, tmpdir))
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clone'

Is there someone that can please explain to me what does this mean?
Many thanks,
Fabio

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I'm tring to install it with easy_install

Comment: If I try to install it with the command "setup.py install" it return the error "no R command in the Path".

Answer (score 1):

rpy2 > 2.0.x is currently not supported on MS Windows.

Comment: Can one still get the 2.0.8 version for win32 (with its documentation?)

Comment: Yes. It is on Sourceforge. There is a also a contributed tentative build for the 2.2.x series somewhere in the issue tracker (bitbucket site).